# I have a problem reading CSS files with Flask Python

Tags: python, css, flask, web, web-applications

let's say I havw an HTML base template called base.html.
In there I write in the  tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/mystyle.css')}}">
```

First everything works fine, but every time i'm doing some changes to the CSS file, and run the flask app,
the page does not refresh with the new changes.
Everytime i need to change the CSS file name to exmaple:mystyle1.css and change the line above, and only then the page loads with the new changes..
Why is it working like that?

I'm working with PyCharm

*EDIT: finally I found similiar question to mine.
the solution i find: after updating and saving the css file, i need to refresh the page in the browswer with SHIFT + CTRL + R (clears the browser's cache for the page)
and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code like this :- 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/mystyle.css')}}">` 
Can you also please tell which code editor do you use for writing html, css and javascript so that I can help you more.

Comment: I'm using pycharm for css, html and js for now,,, and the code you gave is just without the: type="text/css ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're observing is CSS being cached in the browser. And, as you've noted, you can force it to refresh from the browser side.

A common approach this nuisance is to employ "cache busting". Change the URL every time the underlying file changes. One way to do this is to to take the timestamp of the file whenever the app starts, then include that along with the URL. E.g.,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}?v={{ style_css_mtime }}" />
```

Then calculate `style_css_mtime` when the app starts up

```
style_css_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static', 'style.css')
style_css_mtime = int(os.stat(style_css_path).st_mtime)
```

and 'inject' it via a context processor

```
@app.context_processor
def cache_busters():
    return {
        'style_css_mtime': style_css_mtime,
    }
```

This will guarantee that the URL generated will reflect your CSS as of app startup. If you edit your CSS while the development server is running, you'll still need for do a force reset from the browser side. Avoiding this is left as an exercise (with the hint that `@app.before_request` can help).